# Deleting a branch with an invalid name in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I've been using Dropbox to keep my source folder synced between two computers. This folder contains my source-code which I version handle with Git.

it seems that there was a file conflict and when I did a push, my Git client, pushed an invalid branch to the remote. The branch name is `rel_1 (Mridang-PC's conflicted copy 2011-09-16).0-alpha2`. I need to delete this branch but an unable to do so. Ad you can see the name has spaces and single-quote too.

When I try and check out the branch by running: `git checkout "rel_1 (Mridang-PC's conflicted copy 2011-09-16).0-alpha2"`. I get an error saying: `fatal: git checkout: we do not like 'rel_1 (Mridang-PC's conflicted copy 2011-09-16).0-alpha2' as a branch name.`

Is there a way I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious: how to make Git create such a weird branch name?

Comment: It was Dropbox that messed it up. :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in the folder ".git/refs/heads", you will find the file which has that branch name.

(By the way, the branch was renamed that way by Dropbox).

Rename that file, and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey Oliver. Would I rename this file locally or on the remote Git sever?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with a branch named '-t' ( which I definitely did not push to another box)

I ended up going into my .git directory running
find . |xargs grep "-t"
and removing lines associated with the -t from all the files

specifically
 ./packed-refs, 
 ./config ( the whole section associated with it)
 ./into/refs